# Oracle: Network access denied by access control list

Tags: oracle

I'm running Oracle 18c XE.

I'm trying to connect to the following URL:

```
URL := 'https://domain.example.com/api'
apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => URL, p_http_method => GetOrPost, p_body => RequestBody);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1283
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 924
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
```

I tried to create an ACL for that:

```
exec DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl => 'MyACL.xml', description => 'MyACL', principal => 'Schema', is_grant => true, privilege => 'connect'); 
exec DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl => 'MyACL.xml', principal => 'Schema', is_grant  => true, privilege => 'resolve'); 
exec DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => 'MyACL.xml', host => '*', lower_port => 443, upper_port => 443);
```

I tried several assigns:

```
exec DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => 'MyACL.xml', host => 'domain.example.com/api', lower_port => 443, upper_port => 443); 
exec DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => 'MyACL.xml', host => 'domain.example.com/api');
```

None is working. What can I try next?

Comment: To which schema did you grant access through the ACL?

Comment: I believe the ACL has to be for the APEX owner (APEX_190200 or similar), instead of (or possible as well as?) your actual user? Can't verify though... [This might be helpful](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_web_service-consuming-soap-and-rest-web-services).

Comment: @pmdba I granted access to Apex Workspace admin. But in all cases, i'm trying to connect via SQL Developpler to the URL from the Schema I granted the privileges to. Normally that should not be a problem.